# eror with driver.find_element.send_keys

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import json, time


cookies_file = 'cookies.json'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")

time.sleep(2)

with open(cookies_file, "r") as f:
        cookies = json.load(f)
        for cookie in cookies:
            driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.refresh()
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/item/25618282287771238/?ref=browse_tab&referral_code=marketplace_top_picks&referral_story_type=top_picks')

comment_field = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"textarea")
comment_field.send_keys("test")


print(comment_field)



time.sleep(2000)
```

I need a code that will search for an element to send text and then send text, unfortunately I get an error after entering my code, please help me

```
``
comment_field = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"textarea")
comment_field.send_keys("test")


``
```

doesent work, help please